# Unable to use String.contains() in Kotlin 'if' expression

Tags: string, list, kotlin, contains

**Koltin**

I have created a **list** of things and want to skip those things which do not contain the character **'o'** in them. For which I am using the `str.contains()` function, but this is throwing error for me.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val list = listOf<Any>("book", "table", "laptop", "pen")
    for (str in list) 
      {
        if (**!str.contains('o')**) 
        {
            continue
        }
        println(list)
      }
}
```

Comment: Note that, once you fix the type issue, you can also do `if ('o' in str)`.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `listOf<Any>`, what you are essentially saying, this list can have any type of object. It can be `Int`, `String`, or `Any`.

For example, this is perfectly valid:

```
    val list = listOf<Any>(1, "table", 'c', true, 3.0)
    println(list)
    -------------
    [1, table, c, true, 3.0]
```

But, with that compiler lost the ability to infer the specific type of object this list might contain.

So, when you do this:

```
    val list = listOf("my", "username", "is", "saiful103a")
```

or

```
    val list = listOf<String>("my", "username", "is", "saiful103a")
```

The compiler can infer and you will not face any problem:

```
    for(item in list){
        println(item.contains('m'))
    }
```

With that being said, there are two solutions.
Using smart cast:

```
    val list = listOf<Any>(1, "table", 'c', true, 3.0)
    for(item in list){
        if(item is String){
            println(item.contains('t'))   
        }
    }
```

Another is, you can specify or let the compiler infer what the type is, using
`listOf("my", "username", "is", "saiful103a")` or `listOf<String>("my", "username", "is", "saiful103a")`.

Answer (score 2):

[`contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html) is a function on `CharSequence`. Your `str` is of type `Any` and it does not have `contains` function.

One solution is to change the `listOf<Any>` to `listOf<String>`. `String` is a `CharSequence`.

Comment: Or don't specify the type explicitly at all, and just leave the compiler to infer it.